# How can I find out what are the available context links which can be used when creating identities in Platform of Trust?

Tags: api, platform, ontology-network, platform-of-trust

I want to create identity network with Rooms and Sensors. I found in [API documentation](https://docs.oftrust.net/?shell#identities-v1) some example with Group :

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -d \
"{
  \"context\": \"https://standards.lifeengine.io/v1/Context/Identity/Group/\",
  \"type\": \"Group\",
  \"data\": {
    \"name\": \"Company Oy\"
  }
}" "https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/identities/v1"
```

How can I find out what I need to use as value for context if I want to create Room, Sensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Context API built by Platform of Trust. This API provides means to list available JSON-LD contexts of the Platform of Trust.

GET all supported contexts in the Platform using:

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/contexts/v1/"
```

For creating a Room identity you should do:

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -d \
"{
  \"context\": \"https://standards.oftrust.net/v1/Context/Identity/Room/\",
  \"type\": \"Room\",
  \"data\": {
    \"name\": \"Bedroom\"
  }
}" "https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/identities/v1"
```